# OpenStreetMap al parecer no es preciso

Tags: mapa

Quiero empezar a usar OSM con Leaflet para un desarrollo, pero al usar el mapa en su pagina oficial me doy cuenta que el buscador no es para nada preciso a pesar de detallar "Calle, Numero, Ciudad, Pais" y estas cuatro en diversos ordenes me manda la mayoria de las veces a lugares que no son correctos.

¿Sera que el buscador no es preciso o quizas existe otro patron para una busqueda exitosa?

Comment: Siempre hay que comenzar por la [documentación](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Overview/) de la API que quieres usar. En este caso, de Nominatim, que es lo que usa OpenStreetMap. Quité la etiqueta javascript porque tu pregunta no tiene ningún código javascript